# .gitignore - how to ignore file by matching start and end of name

Tags: git, gitignore

I am using *.gitignore* for a C# solution and I'd like to ignore a file that's generated on build, to stop it getting checked in. The only consistent parts of the file name are the start and the end.  Example:

**Cloud.Core**[.example1.example2.example3]**.xml**

It always begins with "Cloud.Core" and ends with ".xml".  It could have various connotations in between, such as:

- Cloud.Core.xml
- Cloud.Core.Example1.xml
- Cloud.Core.Example2.Example2.xml

What mask should I add to my gitignore to bypass a file which has a start/end as described?

I've tried these and a few other variations with luck:

- Cloud.Core*.xml
- Cloud.Core[a-z[.]].xml

I know gitignore uses globbing but I can't seem to work out the correct combination I need:
http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

Thanks for any pointers in advance.

Comment: `Cloud.Core*.xml` works perfect for me

Comment: `Cloud.Core*.xml` should work fine, `.gitignore` is case sensitive. Make sure you get upper/lower-case letters right.

Comment: Actually, that was it! I had everything at lowercase and that caused the file to be picked up, thanks guys!!!

Comment: If you guys can add that as the answer, I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer supplied by @blami

Setting "Cloud.Core*.xml" ignored the file as expected.  This was the solution for me!